# Получить html определенного li

Tags: jquery

Доброго дня столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, необходимо обратится к определенному `li`

```
var s_html = $('#slider91 li').index(1).html();
```

И вытащить его html код содержащийся в нем. Но вместо кода элемента почему то выводит '2' намекая на внутренний параметр из `$('#slider91 li').index(1)`

```
childElementCount: 2
```

Как можно получить `html` из этого `li`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var s_html = $('#slider91 li');
var result = s_html.eq('номер элемента').html(); // s_html.eq(5).html()
```